# How to regexp in MySql json string

Tags: mysql, json, regex

Let's assume this `users` table:

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | ... | info                       |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | ... | {"items":["132","136"]}    |
```

I need to make a request to fetch `users` that have items with `id == 136`.
This following is the `sql` I built but it does not work and I dont understand why:

```
SELECT _u.id FROM users _u WHERE _u.info REGEXP '("items":)([)("136")(])'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `SELECT _u.id FROM users _u WHERE _u.info like '"136"'  `

Comment: Why don't you use myaql's json functions instead?

Comment: @maha It might work but considering accuracy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using the MySQL JSON functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.items"), 'one', "136") IS NOT NULL;
```

### Demo

The call to `JSON_EXTRACT` first extracts the JSON array under the `items` key.  Then, we use `JSON_SEARCH` to try to find an element `"136"`.

**Edit:**

If you are certain that the JSON to be searched would always just be one key `items` along with a single level JSON array, then `REGEXP` might be viable here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE json REGEXP '"items":\\[.*"136".*\\]';
```

### Demo

Comment: Mysql has thrown this error: FUNCTION dev.JSON_SEARCH does not exist

Comment: What is your MySQL version?  If you're using a very old version, then it may not have full JSON support.  In that case, and assuming you expect a need to work with JSON, then consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: 5.0.12 in local but even my prod hosting has thrown the same error.

Comment: It is running in the demo, this is all I can observe here.

Comment: I agree but i assume this is not the only way to achieve this. My regex is likely wrong.

Comment: @dovstone OK I have given you an option using `REGEXP`, but note carefully that in general searching JSON content using regular expression is generally a very bad idea.  If your JSON to search is anything other than what you showed us, `REGEXP` could backfire and return false positives.